# Recover Essbase data

Tags: backup, recover, hyperion, essbase

User has accidentally deleted Essbase application from the EAS Console. 
An application with the same name was created.
We then used Hyperion Planning to recreate the database of the new application.
We have file system backup of all the directories of the deleted application.
How can we get all the data of the old application into the new one?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Let's say the app is called "HPlan", so you have a \app\HPlan folder on your Essbase server. Within the HPlan folder there are several subfolders for each database, such as HPlan, Capex, Wrkforce, and so on.

1. Stop the entire app using EAS
2. Move the entire contents of the app\HPlan folder to a temporary folder
3. Place the backup contents into the app\HPlan folder so that it looks the same as before. So if before you had \app\HPlan\HPlan\HPlan.otl and \app\HPlan\HPlan\HPlan.ind and so on, you would see those again.
4. Start the app and see if it works.
5. Try to login via Planning and see that it works.

This will only work assuming the app was never deleted from Hyperion Planning itself. If you recreated or created a new app in Planning itself then this won't work. In that case you would need to roll the database (SQL Server, Oracle, etc) back to a previous point so that you still had all of the metadata that's in Planning.

Good luck -- if this helps please mark it as helpful so that more people are encouraged to answer Essbase questions on Stack Overflow!